# User profile service on multiple farms

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service, synchronisation, service

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-prem farn, with 2 Front End and 2 Application servers. The User Profile services run on the application servers. We experience every day that the "User Profile Synchornization Service" goes down and gets the status "stopped" on one of the servers. Which leads me to this question, can the "User Profile Synchronization Service" run on 2 servers, in our case 2 application servers, in a farm?

It would be strange if it couldn't, but I am asking this because I am not finding any logical reason for why this happens.

In my experience this service has been very unstable. Any body else that share my experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User profile service can be started on multiple server but user profile syncnorization service should be started on one server.

Further u have to check the uls logs for the clue why it's stoped...also check event viewer.

Comment: Thanks for your input Waqas. Do you know if there is any particular reason to start it on one server only ?

Comment: i think, it is due to Sync and UPA one-to one relationship...One UPs associate with one UPA. if you want multiple instance of UPS...then you have to create the 2nd UPA service application and then start the sync on different server.

Answer (score 1):

initially & during the first time configuring the user profile service application, SharePoint will ask you to select the synchronization instance for the SharePoint Farm and you will have to select only 1 machine in the farm even if you have multiple servers running!!